# =hyperlink function: how to extract the result

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets, extract

I have several names in column A on a spreadsheet which I turn into a clickable hyperlink called "Line is produced here" using this function:

=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.anysite.co.uk/?s=",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","+"),"&post_type=product"),"Link is produced here")

For example, if cell A1 contains Nottingham City Centre, the function correctly allows a url to be launched in a new window as: http://www.amysite.co.uk/?s=Nottingham+City+Centre&post_type=product

I want to be able to extract this url and put it into it's own cell on a Google sheet.

Is there a script that can do this please?

Best wishes.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89557)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd already explored that solution. This question isn't a duplicate, it's a different problem. With thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By chance, I have found a work around using Google sheets alone without the requirement for a script:

In cell A1, write the search terms e.g. Nottingham City Centre

Separate the three component parts of the hyperlink into three cells on a Google sheet, namely cells B1, C1 AND D1:

Cell B1: http://www.anysite.co.uk/?s=
Cell C1: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","+")`
Cell D1: &post_type=product

In cell E1 write:

=B1&C1&D1

Google sheets returns a hyperlink and no script needed after all.